# Inserting id from another table for a hasMany relationship - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, foreign-keys

The database consists of two tables; 1 table named project and 1 table named tasks. 
A project can have multiple tasks. 
Using a multi-select dropdown, multiple elements (users) can be selected and via an array sent to the database.

The insertion of user works fine but the project ids insertion is not working properly. 'null' is inserted instead of the id refer to project.

I can't find where I am missing something. Thanks for the help.

Output:

```
   array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
          "project_id" => null
          "user" => "Jan"
        ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
          "project_id" => null
          "user" => "Piet"
        ]
  ]
```

#### Project table

```
        +----+------+------+-----------------+
        | id | Name | Time |      What       |
        +----+------+------+-----------------+
        | 1  | Test |  123 | Testing project |
        |  2 | Tell |    2 | Knowing project |
        |  3 | Pet  |    5 | Telling pets    |
        +----+------+------+-----------------+
```

#### Tasks table

```
        +----+------+-----------+
        | id | user | poject_id |
        +----+------+-----------+
        |  1 | Jan  |   1       |
        |  2 | Piet |   1       |
        |  3 | Tom  |   2       |
        +----+------+-----------+
```

#### Project.php

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Taks', 'project_id');
}
```

#### Task.php

```
public function project()
{

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'id', 'project_id');
}
```

#### ProjectTasksController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task();
    $data = $request->all();

    foreach ($request->get('user') as $user){
        $users[] = [
            'project_id' => $request->project_id,
            'user' => $user
        ];
}
dd($users);
```

#### show.blade.php

```
<form action="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks" method="post" >
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="user">New User</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="multiSelect" name="user[]">
        <option>Jan</option>
        <option>Piet</option>
        <option>Nele</option>
        <option>Tom</option>
        <option>Tony</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New user</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Result dd($request->all());

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "xxxx"
  "user" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Jan"
    1 => "Piet"
  ]
]
```

#### web.php

```
Route::post('/projects/{project}/tasks',    'ProjectTasksController@store');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it thanks to the input from @Nagesh and @Jinal.
 Using route model binding and give the id with the store function as well see code:

```
    public function store(Request $request, Event $event)
{
    $location = new Location();
    $data = $request->all();

    foreach ($request->get('location_name') as $name){
        $names[] = [
            'event_id' => $event->id,
            'location_name' => $name
        ];
    }

    dd($names);
```

Answer (score 1):

replace relationship method with below:

**Task.php**

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'id', 'project_id');
}
```

typo in Project model:

**Project.php**

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'project_id');
}
```

**ProjectTasksController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request, $project)
{
$task = new Task();
$data = $request->all();

foreach ($request->get('user') as $user){
    $users[] = [
        'project_id' => $project,
        'user' => $user
    ];
}
dd($users);
```

Comment: @Nemo what is your tables name? and dd the `$request->all()` in controller.

Comment: My table names are projects and tasks. I added the result of request all to my question.

Comment: @Nemo is it `location_name`? not `user`? and it is going to in right route?

Comment: Sorry, it was the output from another table. I added the route.

Comment: @Nemo please add routes.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending Project ID by form action URL, you need to catch this in the controller's method.

```
public function store(Request $request, $projectID)
{
    $task = new Task();
    $data = $request->all();

    foreach ($request->get('user') as $user){
        $users[] = [
            'project_id' => $projectID,
            'user' => $user
        ];
}
```

In the `web.php`, you need to add project ID parameter.

Please add a value to the dropdown.

```
<form action="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks" method="post" >
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="user">New User</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="multiSelect" name="user[]">
        <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
        <option value="Piet">Piet</option>
        <option value="Nele">Nele</option>
        <option value="Tom">Tom</option>
        <option value="Tony">Tony</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New user</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't I have still something else to do in order to send the project_id?

Comment: Thanks for the input. It helps me to solve the problem.